# $window.scrollY , window.scrollY and window.pageYOffset nothing is working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angular-material

I tried all the possibilities I know and which I found in Stackoverflow to get `window.scrollY` value it always gave me "0" even same with window.scrollX. Please, can somebody suggest me what I'm doing wrong?

I tried `$window.scrollY`, `$document[0].documentElement.scrollTop` ,`$document[0].documentElement.scrollLeft`, `$window.pageYOffset` , `angular.element($window)` nothing is working for me.

**This is my code snippet** (angular way)

Here in below code

1. topOfNav working great
2. fixNav is triggering on scroll event
3. eventListener is working great
4. **window.scrollY** not working and I'm always getting zero.

   ```
   $timeout(function () {
      var nav = angular.element($document[0].querySelector("#main"));

       // getting this offsetTop value
          var topOfNav = nav.prop('offsetTop');

          var fixNav = function () {
          console.log(topOfNav, $window.scrollY);
         };

     // this is working great, it is listening to scroll event 
        $window.addEventListener('scroll', fixNav, true); 
    });
   ```

To test I tried creating simple HTML file and added this snippet (**javascript way**) in `<script></script>` tag it's working great.

**here** is the code (works like a champ)

```
<script>
  const nav = document.querySelector('#main');
  const topOfNav = nav.offsetTop;
  function fixNav() {
     console.log(topOfNav, window.scrollY);
 }

 window.addEventListener('scroll', fixNav);
 </script>
```

**Additional Information:**

- AngularJS Version: 1.6.2
- Browser Type: chrome
- Browser Version: Version 55.0.2883.87 (64-bit)
- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Thank you.

<strike>**EDIT:**</strike>

**Angular Material Version: 1.x.x**

> After digging too much (Updating Packages, uninstalling and re-installing packages) one thing I found is **Angular-Material is the Blocker**.
>   I tried with other projects of angular too, the only blocker I found was   **Angular Material**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere **removing** the style **height:100%** from the body element, the above code worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

`html, body { height: auto }`